# Python-Selenium Targeting a user within a list of other users

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, targeting

I am trying to target a user in a list of other users. For example I created an automated test case to create a user named "tester1". I would now like to create a test case that finds and deletes "tester1" within a list of other users. Right now my work around is to find element by xpath which only targets a certain row within the user list.
Here is the webpage code that I am working with:

```
<span class="delete" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0.0.1">
  <span class="icon-dash" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0.0.1.0"
  ></span>
```

Here is what I have been using for my workaround.

```
# Finds and clicks minus button to prompt deletion
# Deletes the 4th in the list / to change this, modify the number in the quotes below
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]/td/div/span/span")
element.click()

# Finds and clicks Delete button
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[2]")
element.click()
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="tree-view_children" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1">                          <table class="ss-table" data-reactide=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0">
<tbody data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0">
<tr class="user-list-item" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1">
<td data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0">
<div data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0.0">
<span class="delete" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0.0.1">
<span class="icon-dash" data-    reactid=".0.1.1.0.2.1.0.$usertree.1.0.0.$tester1.0.0.1.0">
</span>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can rely on the tester's name being a part of `data-reactid` attribute:

```
tester = "tester1"

delete_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class = 'delete' and contains(@data-reactid, '$%s.')]" % tester)
delete_button.click()
```

Comment: ^This is the right way to do this. An alternative to XPaths in this case is a CSS Selector, `span.delete[data-reactid*='tester1']`

Comment: @alecxe I traded my lines of code with what you posted. Here are my results: "tester1" was located on the page but "delete_button.click()" did not click the delete button. At this point it gets to the user page finds "tester1" and does nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JeffC I added your suggestion to my code and I got the same results that I posted above ^^^.

Comment: @Chris in this case, could you provide the complete HTML containing other "testers"?

Comment: @Chris also, what browser are you using and are you sure an element is actually clickable? There is probably a button somewhere near the span we've just located..thanks.

Comment: @ alecxe I added and "EDIT" section to the question above with extra HTML source code containing all of the HTML related with tester1. 
I am using firefox
The button is clickable because when I run my workaround code it clicks it.
The page is a list of users with a minus sign next to the user name that if you click it will bring up a little window asking if you want to delete user.